# jquery unbind multiple events by namespace assigned to a single element

Tags: jquery, namespaces, bind, unbind

I know I can write a delegated function like this:

```
$("table").on("click.customNS", "td", function(){
    //do something
});
```

And then to unbind, just:

```
$("table").off(".customNS");
```

So how would it be when it comes to multiple events as shown here:

```
$("table").on({
    click: function(){},
    dblclick: function(){}
}, "td");
```

Where should I write the namespace? So that I can unbind both events with just the namespace

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can unbind both events by the following method.

```
$("table").off("click dblclick","td");
```

Please check the 2nd description of .off() function here: http://api.jquery.com/off